# Can we ever have $E(\arg\!\min(f)) = \arg\!\min(E(f))$?

Tags: statistics, functions, optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Consider a parametric real-valued function $f_{\boldsymbol{\alpha}}: \mathbb D^N \to\mathbb R$ whose parameters $\boldsymbol\alpha$ vary according to some distribution $\psi$, and $\mathbb D$ is either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$ (i.e. reals or integers).

Can we ever have that

$\mathbb{E}_\psi \left(\underset{\mathbf{x}}{\arg\!\min}\; f_{\boldsymbol{\alpha}}(\mathbf{x})\right) = \underset{\mathbf{x}}{\arg\!\min} \; \mathbb E_\psi\left(f_{\boldsymbol{\alpha}}(\mathbf x)\right)$ for some choice of $\psi$ and/or $f$ ?

I am particularly interested in [convex programming problems,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_optimization) that is, when $f$ is convex and only defined within a convex region, and specifically in [LP problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming), when $f$ is also a linear function, but an answer for **any** $f$ would suffice.

A stronger version of this question is **when** would we have LHS $=$ RHS in the Eq. above, but any examples of when LHS = RHS for a linear programming problem would already be very helpful.

Comment: You should add $\alpha$ as a parameter to $f$. The notation is very difficult to read.

Comment: Specifically you seek to know when is
$$\int_\Omega \alpha \mathop{\rm arg\;min}_x(f_\alpha(x))\; \mathrm d\chi(\alpha) = \mathop{\rm arg\;min}_x \int_\Omega \alpha f_\alpha (x) \mathrm d\chi(\alpha)$$
Wich should only hold if $\alpha \mapsto \mathop{\rm arg\;min}_x f_\alpha(x)$ is linear...

Comment: @AlexR I believe your last comment is correct and moves in the right direction.

Comment: Surely that is not equal in general. If $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, the LHS does not even have to be in $\mathbb{Z}$...